# Pandas - Summing two arrays for multiple columns in a group by selecting multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the structure of my data frame. I need to group by based on id, country and state and aggregate the vectors_1 & vector_2 respectively.Please someone suggest how to add the vector for multiple columns

```
Id  Country State    Vector_1                   Vector_2
1     US     IL   [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]   [5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0]

1     US     IL   [5.0,3.0,3.0,2.0,1.0]   [5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0]

2     US     TX   [6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,1.0]   [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
```

The output should looks like this

```
Id  Country State    Vector_1                      Vector_2
1     US     IL   [6.0,5.0,6.0,6.0,6.0]    [10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0] 
2     US     TX    [6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,1.0]    [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm trying with the aggregate function..

Comment: Something like this.. but got stuck up df1.groupby('Id','Country','State').agg({Vector_1:sum})

Comment: Try `.agg({Vector_1: 'sum'}, axis = 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Vector_1` and `Vector_2` are not `np.array`, try to convert them first.

```
cols = ['Vector_1', 'Vector_2']

df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: np.array(x))
```

Then use `groupby` with `apply` to sum each group

```
result = (df.groupby(['Id', 'Country', 'State'])[cols]
            .apply(lambda x: x.sum())
            .reset_index())
result

   Id Country State                   Vector_1                        Vector_2
0   1      US    IL  [6.0, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0]  [10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0]
1   2      US    TX  [6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 1.0]       [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: Accepted the answer. Thanks

Comment: How to implement the same logic in pyspark? I tried 2-3 different logic, but nothing helps. Any advise?

Comment: @prabuster I'm not sure how to do this in pyspark. Maybe you can ask a new question and tag pyspark.